# PHP leaderboard not showing the correct way

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, foreach

I am making a `leaderboard` with persons out of my database. My website is build in PHP (PDO) the problem is that I cant get the users out of the database to show the correct way under each other.

The function I use to get info out of the database is:

```
public function get_klanten(){
    $getKlant = $this->database->query("SELECT * FROM klanten ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
    $klanten = $this->database->resultset();

    return $klanten;
}
```

[image]
[How it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH8oz.png)

The problem I get is that it puts every records after each other and not on a new line that why I added `LIMIT 1` but I want that the second user in this case `Amet` also be out of the database.

The HTML with this is a different file and is the code down below.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Lid</th>
        <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes" aria-hidden="true"></span></th>
        <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>

        <?php
        $klantten = $app->get_klanten();

        foreach ($klantten as $klant) {
            echo '<td>' . $klant['id'] . ' </td>';
            echo '<td>' . $klant['voornaam'] . ' ' . $klant['achternaam'] . ' </td>';
            echo '<td>' . $klant['punten'] . ' </td>';
            echo '<td>' . $klant['punten'] . ' </td>';
        }
        ?>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>amet</td>
        <td>456</td>
        <td>52</td>
    </tr>
```

**BONUS**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="well dash-box">
       <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> Stel jezelf voor</h2>
       <h5><a href="https://tom.lbmedia.nl/onderwerp"> Laat wetn wie jij en je business zijn</a></h5>
   </div>
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="well dash-box">
  <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> 12</h2>
  <?php
  $toppics = $app->get_topics();
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($toppics as $topic) {
 echo '<a href="#section' . $i++ . '">' . $topic['onderwerp'] . '</a>';
  }
  ?>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Function:

```
  public function get_topics(){
        $getTopic = $this->database->query("SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY id DESC");
        $topics = $this->database->resultset();

        return $topics;

    }
```

I want this also to be each record in a new block. So each `topic` is a new block. You can see now 2 blocks I want each block to get a different record out of the database

[image: What it looks like]
    [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH8oz.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH8oz.png

Comment: Recommended not to use `select * from` in queries.

Comment: let us continue in this comment section ;) I did not know about the 90 minutes restriction. You edited one comment to say that the topics appear on the same line. Well, yeah, that's what happens when you chain multiple anchor tags (links). adding a line break after each anchor will help: `<br>`

Comment: mm I am not sure if you get what I really want let me explain: You see those 2 blocks I want every subject to be in 1 of these blocks so a break will just put it under the other in the same block. But I want each record out of the database to be in a different block. @Cashbee

Comment: so every klant belongs to a topic? and under each topic you want to display all its klanten?

Comment: please edit your question with all the new information that you wrote in comments only, I think it will help making it much more understandable. The way you worded your 'bonus' it is not clear at all what you want.

Comment: @Cashbee eddited it, It has nothing to do with the klant (not yet)

Comment: @Cashbee https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508453/php-database-output-not-showing-the-correct-way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove limit 1 from query, then move your TR tag so it's inside your foreach loop.

```
   <?php
   $klantten = $app->get_klanten();

foreach ($klantten as $klant) {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>' . $klant['id'] . ' </td>';
  echo '<td>' . $klant['voornaam'] . ' ' . $klant['achternaam'] . ' </td>';
  echo '<td>' . $klant['punten'] . ' </td>';
  echo '<td>' . $klant['punten'] . ' </td>'; 
  echo '</tr>';
   }

   ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! this solves it! I got a little question and I know it isnt part of the question but maybe you could help, I want to make it sort on the highest number in the column `punten` do you know how to sort like that. So that the record with the highest `punten` is on top @Darloz

Comment: @Tomisnnotdumbmb `... ORDER BY punten DESC` instead of `... ORDER BY id ASC`

Comment: @Cashbee can you check the bonus part out?

Comment: @Tomisnnotdumbmb remove the LIMIT 1 again from the sql, and remove the line `if($j >= 1) continue;`. You also don't need the `$j` var

Comment: @Cashbee and then? because it still doesnt do what i want, than Ill get both on the same line and not in a different block

Comment: @Tomisnnotdumbmb It is not really clear to me what you want actually. It might be better to ask a seperate, new question for your 'bonus'. Changing or adding more questions to an existing one (especially if there are already good answers for the original question) is not the nicest of moves. Also we are mis-using the comment section of this answer ;)

Comment: @Cashbee Hahah I agree and know what u mean but I cant ask a question for 90 minutes so thought If i added a bonus it was still mpossible