# PHP database output not showing the correct way

Tags: php, html, mysql, foreach

I am making a sort of forum with subjects out of my database. My website is built in PHP (PDO) the problem is that I cant get the subject out of the database to show the correct way under each other in each a different block.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="well dash-box">
           <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> Stel jezelf voor</h2>
           <h5><a href="https://tom.lbmedia.nl/onderwerp"> Laat wetn wie jij en je business zijn</a></h5>
   </div>
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="well dash-box">
  <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> 12</h2>
  <?php
  $toppics = $app->get_topics();
  $i = 0;
  $j = 0;
  foreach ($toppics as $topic) {
  if($j >= 1) continue;
 echo '<a href="#section' . $i++ . '">' . $topic['onderwerp'] . '</a>';
  $j++;
  }
  ?>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Function:

```
  public function get_topics(){
        $getTopic = $this->database->query("SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
        $topics = $this->database->resultset();

        return $topics;

    }
```

I want this also to be each record in a new block. In the code, you can see I tried some stuff but it isn't the right way or its not working. I know the `j++` isn't good but if I delete that and the `LIMIT 1` function it doesn't still don't work

[image: What it looks like]

**UPDATE**

If I use the code like it is in the answer given it looks like this and not 2 diffent blocks.

[image]

```
<?php
  $toppics = $app->get_topics();
  $i = 0;
  foreach($toppics as $topic){
     echo '<div>';
     echo '<h3>'.$topic['onderwerp'].'</h3><br>'; 
     echo '<a href="#section' . $i++ . '">'  .$topic['omschrijving'].'</a>';
     echo '</div><br>';
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Why do you set `LIMIT 1` in your query if you're requesting several topics?

Comment: As I said in the quesiton I can leave that away so dont bother about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Since you want to fetch multiple topics from the DB, you must remove the `LIMIT 1` from the query and the `if($j >= 1) continue;` in the foreach loop, as they both are restricting your output to only 1 topic.

In your foreach loop for `$toppics` (correct spelling: topics ;P) you currently only echo an anchor tag (link), but what you want is (to use your words here) a 'block'. Whatever you want that block to look like, the place for defining that is within that foreach loop.

Now I don't know what elements, classes or stylings you use / want to use, so I will make an example of a block that consists of a title and below that the link:

```
//rename $topic keys to the names of your DB columns
foreach($toppics as $topic){
    echo '<div>';
    echo '<h3>'.$topic['title'].'</h3><br>'; 
    echo '<a href="#section'.$topic['id'].'">'.$topic['link_text'].'</a>';
    echo '</div><br>';
}
```

I know my solution will not look exactly like your given image, but it should get the point across how and where you can build your blocks.

I think this problem should have been easily solveable when you know the basics of HTML, so I would really recommend you learning a bit more about HTML before you work on big projects.

---

**Edit** after question was edited:
As I mentioned in my answer, `my solution will not look exactly like your given image` because `I don't know what elements, classes or stylings you use`. Your remaining problem is now the usage of the correct html tags, classes and stylings.

It appears that the parent element of the generated divs is styled the way you want the single blocks to look like.
So what you could do is remove the parent element and use it as a replacement of the generated div, like so:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="well dash-box">
           <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> Stel jezelf voor</h2>
           <h5><a href="https://tom.lbmedia.nl/onderwerp"> Laat wetn wie jij en je business zijn</a></h5>
   </div>
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <!--<div class="well dash-box">-->
  <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> 12</h2>
  <?php
  $toppics = $app->get_topics();
  $i = 0;
  foreach($toppics as $topic){
      echo '<div class="well dash-box">';
      echo '<h3>'.$topic['onderwerp'].'</h3><br>'; 
      echo '<a href="#section' . $i++ . '">'  .$topic['omschrijving'].'</a>';
      echo '</div><br>';
  }
  ?>
  <!--</div>-->
  </div>
```

**sidenote**: I do not agree with your building of your href attribute #section1. When building these sections you would have to know that exact index from that previous foreach-loop. Instead, use some attribute from the topic itself, maybe its ID, title, or description (like I did in the first codeblock). This way when you are building the sections you can easily know how to set the elements id attribute.

Comment: Thanks! can you look at the question again? I updated it with still a small problem

Comment: thx allot its fixed! do you also know how to make a popup with a form to add a new topic? I know how to make the form ect but the code to get it in the db i dont know, its something with the `POST `

Comment: look into modals and AJAX